# Point to node middleware without using port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a website, let's say mywebsite.com
I am using node and express for the middleware and point to mysite.com:3011/api
To make my middleware calls. 
Hosting the site statically in ubuntu 16 (Linux) and running the middleware separately using pm2 (node server)

I would like to simply be able to do something like mysite.com/API without specifying a port in the API call.

Today I tried to demo the site at a corporate office and the apis failed due to not allowing a port to be specified in the URL.

Comment: You can use something like NGINX as a proxy on port 80 to forward any requests for `mysite.com/api` to your node.js server running on some other port and to forward everything else to your static web server on some other port.  So, basically you use NGINX to split incoming request to two other ports based on the content of the URL.  So, the URLs are specified with with no port number (and thus are on port 80) and the proxy splits the request to the appropriate other port/server on the same box.

Comment: Can you please provide a config example? Also isn't there a way to do this without NGINX?

Comment: You can do it without NGINX, but you have to code forwarding functionality into whatever web server you have running on port 80 so that it can identify the URLs that you want to forward and then it forwards them to another server on another port and pipes the response back to the origin.  That's what NGINX already has built-in.  This is a very basic feature of NGINX. I'd suggest you read the documentation for it and ask a more specific question if you get stuck after reading the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse proxy (like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com)) to hide this port and forward the request to your Node.js api. 
Something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    ...

    location / {
         root /path/to/static/files;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3011;
    }

    ...

}
```